# Special case for time range in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime, date-range

I am facing an issue doing a special case for time range. I have a function which decides if a time is within the range.

```
function check_time($start, $end){
    $start = date( 'H:i', strtotime( $start ) ); // ex: 11:00 AM
    $end   = date( 'H:i', strtotime( $end ) );   // ex: 2:00  PM
    // check the range
    if ( current_time( 'H:i' ) > $start && current_time( 'H:i' ) < $end ) {
      return true;
    }
}
```

this works for different cases but it fails if end time pass midnight to next day.

```
for example, assume the current time is 3:00 PM
6:00 AM - 10:00 PM // true
1:00 PM - 9:00  PM // true
2:00 PM - 1:00  AM // false  // should be true
2:00 PM - 2:00  AM // false  // should be true
```

How can I avoid the test to fail in these special cases and return true even if it passes the midnight?

Comment: use the full date and time instead of just the hour and minutes.

Comment: when passing the start and end variables or during calculations?

Comment: you would need to pass them in and compare them as date and time.

Comment: if we do comparison based on date, it would still fails because after midnight it is a different date

Comment: as long as `$start` and `$end` represent a date and time then it will work. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish the cases where `$start` is less than `$end` and vice versa.

When `$start` is less than `$end`, you can simply test whether the current time is between them.

When `$start` is greater than `$end`, it means thhe time period crosses midnight. In that case, you should test if the current time is after `$start` **OR** it's before `$end`, rather than **AND**.

```
function check_time($start, $end){
    $start = date( 'H:i', strtotime( $start ) ); // ex: 11:00 AM
    $end   = date( 'H:i', strtotime( $end ) );   // ex: 2:00  PM
    $cur = current_time( 'H:i' );
    if ($start < $end) {
        return $cur > $start && $cur < $end;
    } else {
        return $cur > $start || $cur < $end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `$start` and `$end` are already representative of the date and time (they should be or `strtotime` will not work as expected) then do:

```
if( time() > strtotime($start) && time() < strtotime($end) ) {
    return true
}
```

Comment: `start` and `end` are not representative of date but just time. So just `11:00 AM`